# Specify options available on API endpoint for a path variable with Swagger in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0, path-variables

I have the following controller method

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Send a signin request with a provider")
@GetMapping("/{provider}/signin")
public void signIn(@PathVariable String provider, HttpServletResponse response) {
    service.signIn(provider, response);
}
```

And what I want to know is if there is **way to specify the possible values**, that can be passed in the **provider path variable**. 
On the Swagger docs I see something about enums, but I don't know how to use this on my Spring Boot app. 
And on the SpringFox docs I couldn't find the word enum.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is sample code for generating available options. This example shows how to multi-select available options. Just use String instead of List for single select

```
@GetMapping(value = "/request/......", produces = {"application/xml"})
public ResponseEntity<?> createMandate(@NotNull @ApiParam(value = "Test 
Case", required = true, allowableValues = "happy-path, dirty-path, wrong-
path") @RequestParam(value = "TestCase", required = true) List<String> 
testCases,
                                                           @NotNull 
@ApiParam(value = "Another Text Field input") @RequestParam(value = 
"CustomerMSISDN", required = true) String customerMsisdn) {
    return ??
}
```